# Receive message when push notification is disable

Tags: php, android, ios, unity-game-engine, onesignal

In order to let server send mobile app client a message,

I want to use push notification.

But if user disable the app notification, the message cannot be received.

Can i do something to receive push notification message in the app?

Or other method can let server send a message to mobile app?

My development environment : Unity3D, OneSignal(Push notification Library), LNMP

Comment: You can send silent pushes to your app;  As long as your app hasn't been terminated by the user then the push will be received in your app delegate.  You don't even need to ask the user for notification permission to receive silent pushes.

Comment: @Paulw11 If I use silent pushes and I disable the app push notification, I still can receive the push notification message in my app, right?